# c# - Get values from XML Nodes with more than one value

Tags: c#, xml

First of all I would like to clarify that I'm noob programming.
Here is my question.
I'm having troubles getting the values of a node with more than one value.
I'm using Xml.Linq.

Example of my XML:

```
<root>
    <ManufactureID>test</ManufactureID>
    <Part>21034015</Part>
    <Fixture>Erowa</Fixture>
    <Material>CrCo</Material>
    <ImplantIndex IMP="IMP1">
        <Position x="26,61927" y="3,666112" z="-13,54083"/>
        <Direction x="0,7169617301164524" y="0,41536091911417444" z="-0,5598581824185941"/>
        <Xaxis x="0,7169617301164524" y="0,41536091911417444" z="-0,5598581824185941"/>
        <Yaxis x="0,4630894965759858" y="0,31652069765969354" z="0,8278663938788802"/>
        <Zaxis x="0,52107004875489" y="-0,8528129659108433" z="0,034583948081838636"/>
    </ImplantIndex>
    <ImplantIndex IMP="IMP2">
        <Position x="27,20444" y="3,832021" z="-5,81747"/>
        <Direction x="0,5516120001302346" y="0,2908829003330433" z="-0,7817361061164817"/>
        <Xaxis x="0,5516120001302346" y="0,2908829003330433" z="-0,7817361061164817"/>
        <Yaxis x="0,7202426402494431" y="0,30658331713284814" z="0,6222999347760941"/>
        <Zaxis x="0,420683658440441" y="-0,9063077887504092" z="-0,04039123136907434"/>
    </ImplantIndex>
</root>
```

For getting the nodes value of Part,Fixture or Material I have not problem.
But for getting the x/y/z values of position and direction actually I'm using:

```
  string position = doc.Root.Element("ImplantIndex").Element("Position").ToString();
  string[] posTokens = position.Split('"');
  Console.WriteLine(double.Parse(posTokens[1]));
  Console.WriteLine(double.Parse(posTokens[3]));
  Console.WriteLine(double.Parse(posTokens[5]));
```

Anyone can help me getting a better way for doing that last part?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you try to get attribute value?

Comment: Eww, don't `ToString()` it and work on it that way. Access the attributes directly from that element.

Comment: Please edit your question, and fix the XML making it well-formed.

Comment: Yes, I tried to get the attribute but when it has more than one value I can't get it. Thats why I used ToString().

Answer (score 1):

This is how you normally access attribute value at node:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<book genre='novel' ISBN='1-861001-57-5'>" +
            "<title>Pride And Prejudice</title>" +
            "</book>");

XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;

// Check to see if the element has a genre attribute.
if (root.HasAttribute("genre")){
  String genre = root.GetAttribute("genre");
  Console.WriteLine(genre);
}
```

or using XElement

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("PurchaseOrder.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> address =
    from el in root.Elements("Address")
    where (string)el.Attribute("Type") == "Billing"
    select el;
foreach (XElement el in address)
Console.WriteLine(el);
```

Comment: It is much better to use LINQ to XML API. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.